# Reference Reassignment

Tags: c++, reference, heap-memory

I have a general C++ question.

Lets say I have this code:

```
int& GetInt()
{
    int* num = new int();
    return *num;
}

int numCopy = GetInt();
```

In this situation, what happens to the returned reference? This example uses a simple data structure so it doesn't really matter, but in cases where the returned data is more complex, would assigning a variable to a heap-allocated variable reference like this copy the data over to `numCopy` completely, or would `numCopy` become another reference to the original `num`?

Comment: You're assigning a variable _from_ a heap allocated variable reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In this situation, what happens to the returned reference?

It goes out of scope at the end of the full expression and you have now leaked the memory you acquired in `GetInt`.  You've made a copy of the value the reference refers to, but the original object, and the memory it occupies are no longer accessible.

If you had

```
int& foo = GetInt();
```

then you could later on do

```
delete &foo;
```

to not have a memory leak, but this is still bad practice.

---

> or would `numCopy` become another reference to the original `num`?

You only ever get a reference if you specifically ask for it.

```
int numCopy = GetInt();
```

says `numCopy` is an `int`, not a `int&`, so it will not be a reference.  C++ has what is called [value semantics](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/), which basically means unless you ask for a reference, the object you create is it's own object that is independent from all other objects.

Comment: In my actual project, the heap-allocated variable would be pushed into a globally accessible vector through a static class, so it would still be accessible. So far I've been returning the actual pointer (as in num, not *num), yet I wanted to return a reference as it makes the syntax a bit easier. So just to make sure I'm getting it right, there is no way to enforce that whatever, for example, GetInt() gets assigned into is a reference rather than a copy from the function itself

Comment: @MattanMohel Correct.  You can't enforce it gets assigned to a reference.

Comment: Oh well, that's kind of annoying. Anyways, thank you very much

Comment: You can't really even ensure that some fool won't dereference the pointer and store a copy should you choose to return the pointer instead. Mind you, their choice might not be all that foolish for their use-case. It's hard to predict how people will use your API. Most of the time they'll  <expletive deleted> it up when they paint outside the lines, but sometimes they come up with really, really cool applications you never thought of.

Comment: In that case I could make the copy constructor private or simply delete it. But you're right, if someone goes out of their way to specifically do this, there's always the chance they know what they're doing. In this case pointers would be safer for someone who's inexperienced and would still permit flexibility to the more advanced

Comment: @MattanMohel If you wan't, you could embrace the value system and have something like [the proposed `std::observer_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr).  That gives you a descriptive name for the pointer, you know that your not to manage its life, and you can pass it around by value but you still have a "reference".

Comment: That sounds ideal, I'll read into it. Although I usually prefer to stick with raw pointers. Thanks either way